# Why VS and gcc call different conversion operators here (const vs non-const)?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants, operator-keyword

This piece of code is dumb of course, but I only wrote it to illustrate the issue.
Here it is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct foo {
    int a = 42;

    template <typename T>
    operator T* () {
        cout << "operator T*()\n";
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&a);
    }

    template <typename T>
    operator const T* () const {
        cout << "operator const T*() const\n";
        return reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&a);
    }

    template <typename T>
    T get() {
        cout << "T get()\n";
        return this->operator T();
    }
};

int main() {
    foo myFoo;
    cout << *myFoo.get<const int*>() << '\n';
}
```

The output when compiled with Visual Studio 2019 (ISO C++17, `/Ox`) is:

```
T get()
operator const T*() const
42
```

The output with gcc 8.3 (`-std=c++17`, `-O3`) is:

```
T get()
operator T*()
42
```

So I'm wondering why the two compilers opt to call different const-qualified conversions given this code?

If I change `get()` to `get() const`, then both call the `const` version of the conversion. But isn't VS violating the standard by calling the `const` conversion from a method that isn't marked `const`?

**EDIT:**

To clear up some confusion around `reinterpret_cast`, [here's a version without it](https://pastebin.com/jmDfTm34) which still produces the same output on both compilers.

Comment: Because one of them is wrong.
`myFoo.get` is not `const`, so I expect non-`const` cast version to be invoked.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `foo::get<int const*>` calls `foo::operator<int const>`. The return values is, indeed, `const int*`.

Comment: it seems like your code is illustrating a lot more issues than what the question is actually about. Eg do you really need the `reinterpret_cast`s to reproduce the output?

Comment: @user463035818 Don't think so, I just usually write pointer casts with `reinterpret_cast` because it simply takes the address and treats it as a pointer to another type, whereas `static_cast` could alter the behaviour (not in this case though), and C-style pointer casts are just ugly :)

Comment: ugh... `reinterpret_cast` are as ugly as c-style casts. Afaik there is no difference between them whatsoever

Comment: @user463035818 Yeah, no real practical difference. But this is beside the point.

Comment: There are a few cases when `reinterpret_cast` could be okay. But in over 99% of all cases it should be taken as a red flag that you're doing something bad that will almost certainly lead to UB. It works in this specific case because you cast to basically the same types (`int*` to `const int*`). If the member variable or the template argument was different, then you would have broken strict aliasing. So, what is the *real* problem you want so solve? Why did you come up with this example? Perhaps you should ask about the underlying problem instead?

Comment: yes exactly its beside the point, thats why the example would be nicer without it (given that it is not needed to reproduce the output of course), as it is just distracting from the actual question. well... sorry for getting distracted ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In the actual project that this comes from, the size of the pointed type is checked at compile time, and casting to a pointer to a bigger type than the stored data would be caught by a `static_assert`. The code this comes from deals with binary files, so casting pointers is necessary. Don't worry about that part though, my question was about VS calling a `const` function from a non-`const` function, which shouldn't be a thing.

Comment: btw I am starting to belief that the casts are in fact not unrelated to the problem. I dont understand if fully yet, but it is easy to get undefined behaviour via `reinterpret_cast` and then getting the wrong method called is no surprise

Comment: Then please include some background in the question. Or if possible try to come up with a [mcve] that doesn't have the casting. The less distractions and the less possible sources of (unrelated) problems, the easier it will be to help you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude First of all the question was about VS calling a `const` conversion from a non-`const` method, and that seemed inappropriate. That has nothing to do with where the code originated from, as I never stated I'm looking for a solution to something that isn't included in the example. The example I provided perfectly reproduces the issue in itself, and it's only a couple of lines, so imo it absolutely counts as minimal viable example, given that you aren't trying to answer a different question from the one that was asked. Although I did include a different version, see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method:

```
template <typename T> foo::T get();
```

is *not* `const`.

That implies inside its body the object `this` is a pointer to `foo` type (and not `const foo`).

Therefore, the statement

```
this->operator T();
```

is going to call the no-`const` version because of the [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

As the standard states on [`[over.match.best]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best), the version `no-const` is preferred because does not require any *cast*.
Indeed, in order to call the `const` version, the compiler should have implicitly cast into a const object (i.e. `const_cast<const foo*>(this)`).

---

Both [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/VcmDU4) and [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/YfTokW) follow what I have just said.

MSVC simply does not follow the standard here.

Comment: Yes, that is clear to me. What I don't understand is why Visual Studio still opts for calling the `const` version, which is against the rule you described.

Comment: @adam10603 MSVC is not standard compliant.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm starting to suspect too, which wouldn't surprise me. I'll wait a bit, and I'll accept this if nothing else comes up

Comment: There are no methods or member function or conversion operators defined in 'foo'. What is defined are templates. So the question is, which template should be instantiated.

Comment: @BiagioFesta I disagree, this was true in old VC++, new VC++ is standard complianat but this do not mean that is bug free. This should be reported to MS and then fixed by MS.

Comment: @Yankes Sure, Don't take me wrong. I meat that MSVC does not follow the standard *on this particular scenario*, that is, a bug, indeed.

Comment: @BiagioFesta Right, I wrongly interpreted "not standard compliant" as "do not bother with standard" as MS did in '90 and '00.